# How to extract enumerated labels and corresponding numerical values from a .sav file?

Tags: python, r, spss

**How can I extract a mapping of numbers to labels from a `.sav` file without access to SPSS?**

I am working with a non-profit who uses `SPSS`, but I don't have access to `SPSS` (and they are not technical). They've sent me some `SPSS` files, and I was able to extract these into `csv` files which have correct information with an `R` package called `foreign`.

*However* for some files the R package extracts textual labels and for other files the R package extracts numbers. The files are for parallel case studies of different individuals, and when I count the labels vs. the numbers they don't even match exactly (say 15 labels vs. 18 enums because the underlying records were made across many years and by different personnel, so I assume the labels probably don't match in any case). So I really need to see the number to label matching in the underlying enum. How can I do this without access to SPSS?

(p.s. I also tried using `scipy.io` to read the `.sav` file and got the error `Exception: Invalid SIGNATURE: b'$F'` when testing on multiple files before giving up so that seems like a non-starter)

Comment: You can refer http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577811-python-reader-writer-for-spss-sav-files-linux-mac-/ this post

Comment: Thanks @Akash I just tried this package, and it also returns numbers without labels for the first csv file I tried.

Comment: Perhaps http://pythonhosted.org/savReaderWriter/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `R`, you can perhaps use the `haven` package. Of the course the results will depend on the files being imported, but the package does included functions for dealing with/viewing labels (presuming the labels actually exist).

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this recommendation and feel silly I didn't find this. I had even tried out the SPSS free trial software and even that didn't see the labels (I support the group is using an older version of SPSS ?) but haven sees the labels. Happy I can finally get to work knowing what I'm looking at. Thanks!